# How to get momentjs to output 3M Ago instead of 3 Minutes Ago?

Tags: momentjs

Using momentjs I'm trying to output "3M ago" instead of "3 Minutes Ago"

Here is my code:

```
  return moment(date).fromNow();
```

I'm not sure how to format it the way I want so the minute, or hour is just the first letter without white space.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826975/how-do-i-use-two-different-relativetime-customizations/29086841#29086841 The same approach should work for you.

Comment: Yes, as tgo said, customizing the [locale's relative time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) is the only way to do this. If you need to support multiple languages, my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29262910/728393) might help.